# downcast to subclass and get subclass only fields

Tags: java

I have classes similar to DataRequest & DataWithIdRequest.   DataWithIdRequest gets passed into my controller method.  I want to pass the subclass object ONLY to another class for processing.  However, when I try to downcast to  DataRequest  the extra field is still showing.  How can I accomplish this?

```
public class DataRequest {

    private String name;
    

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


public class DataWithIdRequest extends DataRequest {

    private Integer id;

    public Integer getId() {
        return contractKey;
    }

    public void setContractKey(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
    //controller
    
        processData(request);
    }
    
    //domain class
    public Boolean processData(DataRequest request) {
    
        //request here has DataWithIdRequest field
        //but I only want the subclass
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean it's still showing? If you mean in a debugger ok, but `processData` shouldn't be able to call that method unless it casts `request` back to a `DataWithIdRequest`. And why would it without being sure that `request` actually is a `DataWithIdRequest`?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question or problem, but it sounds like you think casting a `DataWithIdRequest` to `DataRequest` or assigning a `DataWithIdRequest` object to a `DataRequest` variable will somehwor convert that object. That is **not** how casting and assigning works. Your `DataWithIdRequest` object will always be a `DataWithIdRequest` object regardless whether you even cast it or assign it to `Object`. If you want to convert it to a different kind of object you will have to do so manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Boolean processData(DataRequest request) {  }
```

Because in your method `processData`, request's type is `DataRequest`.  You want it to be DataWithIdRequest.

```
public Boolean processData(DataWithIdRequestrequest request) {  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only offer a *part* of an API (application programmer's interface), by separating the code in an interface.

```
public interface Identified {
    Integer getId();
    public void setContractKey(Integer id);
}

public class DataWithIdRequest extends DataRequest implements Identified {

    private Integer id;

    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return contractKey;
    }

    @Override
    public void setContractKey(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public Boolean processData(DataRequest request) {
    if (request instanceOf Identified identified) {
        identified.setContractKey(13);
    }
}
```

Or move the problem to the caller:

```
public Boolean processData(Identified request) {
    request.setContractKey(13);
}
```

By the way it more usual to use int, boolean, the primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the information completely, you need to create a new instance of `DataRequest` by `DataWithIdRequest` (that's why mapping library like `mapstruct` is useful), but not directly passing it.

---

Explanation:

This is how inheritance works, imagine a method takes a parameter of an interface or abstract class, by using `instanceof` inside the method we can check the object actual type and do something specific. e.g.

```java
public void drawShape(Shape shape) {
  if (shape instanceof Circle) {
    Circle circle = (Circle) shape;
    // do sth
  } else if (shape instanceof Square) {
    // do sth else
  }
}
```

The above example is completely valid (although not a good programming style, that's another story).

The object inside the memory holds all the actual class details, passing it to a method doesn't change anything to the memory. The parameter (e.g. `shape`) is only another reference to the same memory location.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question fully but: as you want I it's not possible since:

public class DataWithIdRequest extends DataRequest

means DataRequest is a subset of DataWithIdRequest, it's an intersection.

You unfortunately need to find an other way

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).